# How to prevent bootstrap from affecting a particular element and it's child element?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

The below is a working react code which just renders a small table.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
// import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>00</td>
          <td>01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**styles.css:**

```
table {
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  border-collapse: separate;
}

td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

You can see the third line importing bootstrap being commented out in the App.js file. When it is commented out, the table is rendered with borders for each cell and with a space between each cell due to the `border-collapse: separate;` in the css file which is how I want.

When I uncomment it, it imports bootstrap and the borders of the table cells are gone.
In the table tag, I haven't added any bootstrap classes.

Is there any way to prevent this and get my borders back?

Please view my code and execution here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ix81bu?file=src%2FApp.js.

Comment: Just simple solution is add border-collapse: separate !important; in your css class it's overrides incoming bootstrap style that's it.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Uncomment the import bootstrap line to get its styles.
Then try `border-collapse: revert;` instead of `border-collapse: separate;`
This should undo effect of bootstrap's effect on `border-collapse`.

Option 2:
Uncomment the import bootstrap line to get its styles.
Change `border-collapse: separate;` to `border-collapse: separate !important;` so that it will not be overridden. Refer [Introducing the CSS Cascade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade) for in-depth concepts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it did not work in this case. I was also wondering how bootstrap is overriding the property when I haven't added a bootstrap class to the table.